# Can I restrict website access to specific computers?

Tags: security

I realize that mac addresses or machine ids aren't transferred over the internet, however, I would like to lock down our subscription-based website security so that only specific computers can register and have access to its resources.

Large organizations will subscribe to our service and will undoubtedly have more than one ip for their organization.  As well, we'd like to give the ability for their qualified employees to access the website on devices outside of their physical organization (for road-trip presentations, etc.).

Is there a sure-fire way to achieve this end (beyond the username/password assigned to each account)?  If not, what would be the most effective approach?

Comment: What's wrong with the typical username and password approach? It seems like a headache for both parties if access is restricted to certain devices

Comment: The username and password are implied here, I apologize that I didn't mention it (EDIT: ADDED THIS).  The problem is that these are (very) expensive subscriptions and so we cannot afford to have these accounts shared at all.

Comment: proper legal licensing is the only method of merit here.

Comment: Gotcha. I think this just the cost of doing business. If you're selling to high end clients, you shouldn't have much to worry about.

Comment: A cookie-based machine identification system, like that used by steampowered.com (as well as some banks) could be of value.  User doesn't have a cookie?  Make them verify their control of the browser via email, and then cookie them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of restricting access via IP, you want to use something that's actually secure.

Username and password over an HTTPS connection should at least be unsniffable, but you might want to look in to client SSL certificates.  They can be [configured in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) or other web server software.  If username/password authentication is not enough, this is the next (and perhaps final) step up.

**UPDATE:**

That said, what many application providers will do is provide a method for subscribers to implement an ACL for their accounts.  You can even force people to consider their ACL before allowing them to access your services.  Think of it this way:

- An account is set up in your system allowing login from anywhere.  Upon creation, the ACL is UNSET.
- User logs in and is immediately directed to an ACL setup page, where they must provide either an IP address or range or subnet associated with their account.  You can be clever and pre-populate things with their existing IP address or subnet, perhaps even looking things up at ARIN to see if their IP is in a network assigned to the company name on their account.
- Once the ACL is set (or they have, despite your warnings, confirmed that they want to keep their ACL open), they can access your services.
- If they try log in from elsewhere, they (and you) are notified via email (or SMS or whatever) of an attempted breach.
- If they no longer have access to their ACL-listed IPs (i.e. IP renumbering due to a new upstream Internet provider and bad planning), they can call your phone support who will validate them by other means.  FAX confirmation perhaps, because that's SO secure...

A user-managed ACL is not a "sure-fire" way, but it may be sufficiently effective for your needs, and it will certainly instill a sense in your customers that you have their best interests at heart.

Comment: Could client SSL be copied from computer to computer?

Comment: Yes, it can. It is not restricted to a single computer.

Comment: Yes.  A certificate is a block of data, stored in a file.  If your customer's data are vulnerable, then any access information is also vulnerable, whether it's a certificate or a password vault.  You can only secure the access to your data/application.  It's up to them to secure their computers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure-fire way. That's in the nature of networks. You accept data from a remote machine and you have to trust it at least to some extend.

Take the simple username/password approach. If the usename and the passwords match, you have to trust, that they where entered by the person that the username and password was intended for. This does not fundamentally change if you require more data to be send by the client.